# How to redirect external links in page like Google using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to make a redirect for every external link on my page like Google

when u hover the link it shows the real one but when you click it it becomes a redirect page.

Please Help!!

Thanks.

Comment: That's kinda creepy, I was wondering what was with the links on google only sometimes showing up properly.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use an event listener for the click on the link and change it's `href` attribute.

If you only want to do it for external links, it gets a bit more complicated. This example redirects all links beginning with `http`:

```
var redirect = 'http://redirect.foo?url=';
$('a[href^="http"]').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).attr('href',  redirect + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aev4m/1/

However, please don't use this for bad things. It's not userfriendly at all in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[href]").click(function() { window.location.href = "MyRedirectURL" + $(this).attr("href"); return false;} );
```

*Added*: only for external links

```
$("a[href]").each(function()
{
    if (this.hostname != location.hostname)
        $(this).click(function()
        {
            location.href = "MyRedirectURL" + $(this).attr("href");
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: This affects all links, not just the external ones.